# Abrindo outro página com Angular e Sweet Alert

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert

Estou tentando abrir uma página em javascript com angularjs. Preciso que quando clicar no bt ele faça uma pergunta e dependendo do resultado, abra um link com a url true ou false. Consigo fazer isso, porém a página só é aberta se eu clicar novamente no botão. Segue abaixo o código:

```
$scope.hasCodeIndication = function() {
    // $location.path('/register/true');
    swal({
        title: 'Código de indicação',
        text: 'Possuo código de indicação?',
        confirmButtonText: 'Sim',
        confirmButtonColor: '#16824d',
        closeOnConfirm: true,
        cancelButtonText: 'Não',
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnCancel: true,
        html: true
    },
    function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            $location.path('/register/true');
        } else {
            $location.path('/register/false');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o  `$window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');`

Comment: Consegui fazwendo assim:

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, fazendo assim:

```
**$window.location.href = '/#/register/true';**
```